# javaFX. Remove all event handlers (filters)

Tags: javafx

`removeEventHandler()` is ok, but what if I don't keep reference on handler ?

Can I remove any event handler(filter) by event type or even all handlers from my `JavaFX`. `scene.Node` instance? I guess that somewhere a list of handlers existed, and I can traverse it, and remove what I want.

Answer (score 5):

> Can I remove any event handler(filter) by event type or even all handlers from my javafx.scene.Node instance?

I don't think you can remove an event handler or filter which you didn't have a reference to originally.  You can [add extra event filters](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#addEventFilter%28javafx.event.EventType,%20javafx.event.EventHandler%29) to filter out processing for events by type or you can [set your own event dispatcher on the node](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#setEventDispatcher%28javafx.event.EventDispatcher%29) and have your custom dispatcher only forward the events you want to the node's standard event dispatcher.

> I guess that somewhere a list of handlers existed, and I can traverse it, and remove what I want.

Yes, but that is buried within the [private implementation of the Node](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/openjfx/8/master/rt/file/tip/javafx-ui-common/src/javafx/scene/Node.java), so you probably don't want to hack the private Node code to do that.

Answer (score 4):

I came across this question while looking for how to create event handlers that remove themselves. The answer to my question was here, I don't know if it will help you.
[javafx have an eventfilter remove itself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35568010/javafx-have-an-eventfilter-remove-itself)

Here is an example

```
EventHandler<MouseEvent> object_clicked=new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
        // on click actions here

        my_node.removeEventFilter(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, this); // at the bottom
    }
};

my_node.addEventFilter(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, object_clicked); // add the eventhandler to the node
```